# Number of integral points in the given enclosed region

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

**Questions**:

> How many points with integral coordinates lie inside the region bounded by the lines $|x| = 2$, $x + y = 12$ and $x – y = 5$?

**My Working**:

> I drew the graphs and looked at the extreme points of the trapezium.
>
> Then, I individually confirmed each integral coordinates whether they lie in the given enclosed region. I got $90$ such points.

**Given answer**:

> $48$.

**My Doubt**:

> Who is wrong and why is there such a difference of approximately 2 times between me and the answer key?

Also, **is there** any other (**smarter**) **way** than **to** individually calculate/**identify the integral points** and listing them?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum\limits_{x=0}^8 \left( 1 + \left\lfloor \frac{35 - 4x}{y} \right\rfloor \right) = 30$$

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. +1. Is there a way to calculate that sum, like by using a formula? Or does it need to be summed up case by case?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Divide the region $ABCD$ into into three regions : rectangle $AFED$ and two triangle $ABF$ and $DEC$.

No of points with integer coordinate inside the rectangle $AFED $ (including the points on $AF$ and $ED$ ) is $$14×5-2\times 14=42$$

---

[image]

Let us consider the rectangle $DECG$.

No. of points with integer coordinate inside the rectangle $DECG$ is $$5\times 5-2\times (5+ 3)=9$$

**Remove no.of diagonal entries with integer coordinate and divide by $2$**

No. of points with integer coordinate inside the triangle $DEC$ is $$\frac{9-3}{2}=3$$

---

Similarly no. of points with integer coordinate inside the triangle $ABF$ is $3$.

---

Hence total number of points with integer coordinate inside the region $ABCD$ is $42+3+3=48$

Comment: Thank you for the answer! +1. Is there a way that I don't have to create such accurate graphs and still get an answer?

Comment: Let's wait for better answers. Probably Combinatorics can be helpful here (which I don't know).